# initializing multidimensional Line array in silverlight

Tags: arrays, silverlight, initialization, line

i am making an application in silver light. In that application i am using three dimensional line array but i am not getting how to initialize it?I have array as

```
Line[,,] line = new Line[10,20,30];
```

How can i initialize every value with new line?Please help me.Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will `line.Initialize()` initialize every elements in the array with the default constructor of the Line.

Cheers!
Vinod